# Sum of three i.i.d. uniform random variables

Tags: probability

This is from an online game.

Assume 990 "Hitpoints" for both yourself and the opponent.

Assume max hit for the weapon you're using is 470; and the hits you can have ranges from inclusive 1 to inclusive 470 1(1-470 all possible, not zero).

What are the chances that you defeat your opponent in 3 hits (getting his hit points to zero)? I'm not sure what method I need to be using to get this probability question on point.

*This question excludes and ignores what the opponent will hit (assume he doesn't hit you).

Comment: Not that it matters much to the end result, but can I only hit for an integer amount, or can I do, say, $\pi$ damage?

Comment: Are we assuming that the number of hit points your weapon produces is a random integer between $1$ and $470$?

Comment: Assuming integer hits, sum up the coefficients of $x^n$ with $n \geq 990$ in $\dfrac{(x^{471} - x)^3}{(x - 1)^3}$ and divide by $470^3$ to get your answer.

Comment: Which gives $\frac{266493}{2209000} \approx 0.120640$.